# Trespassing to recover stolen property

Tags: nevada

Say someone steals my car (or whatever). Am I allowed to trespass to retrieve the car? It shouldn't  be trespassing if I am defending my property.

The other question  implies eg a store grabbing  a shoplifter is illegal, which makes no sense.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If someone steals something of mine, is it legal to steal it back?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/15869/if-someone-steals-something-of-mine-is-it-legal-to-steal-it-back)

Comment: That seems to answer no, but I need confirmation. Otherwise someone can steal something and put  it on their lawn (for example) and then I would  have to stop pursuing. Or put  it in their bag or some minor  thing.

Comment: Correct: if you see your stolen property on someone's lawn, you are supposed to stop pursuing.  Then *call the police.*

Comment: You might convince the prosecutor not to bring trespass charges against you if the person whose land was trespassed against was a car thief, but you couldn't guarantee that result. There are citizen's arrest rules but they would rarely apply if not in hot pursuit.

Comment: A store ordinarily grabs a shoplifter in a citizen's arrest on its own property, so it isn't trespassing. See https://www.shouselaw.com/nevada/citizens-arrest

Comment: But its trespassing inside their bag and its assault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are not allowed to break the law (trespassing) to enforce the law.

This boils down to: 'two wrongs don't make a right'.

A law enforcement officer is allowed to enter the property to determine (or to collect the needed information for a prosecuter) if your claim is correct (your car on someone elses property that may have been stolen).

A officer is trained to collect evidence (or secure the area untill someone else does) in a manner acceptable to a court.

The court will consider evidence collected by the law enforcement officials to be **impartial** and therefore it is in your interest (as a person that is envolved in the matter, thus impartial) to have the police deal with this matter properly.

---

> So what about a bag? If a shoplifter puts an item in their own bag dont you have to violate their property to retrieve it?

No, this would be a violation of [Equality before the law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equality_before_the_law) or the [Golden Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Rule):

- *Do unto others as you would have them do unto you*

and is the backbone of **civil code** and **common law** jurasdictions (*ius respicit aequitatem*) and thus implemented in one form or another.

You must ask yourself the following question:

- how would you feel, if a compleate stranger came up, grabbed your bag to search for something **they *claim*** belongs to them?

Most peaple (including a judge) wouldn't like that at all.

In such cases the police must be called.

In cases of *in flagrante delicto* a [Citizen's arrest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizen%27s_arrest) for the **detainment** of the person until the police arrive *may* be made in most jurisdictions.

Depending on the situation, the police themselfs made need a search warrant.

So the threshold is *very high* and care must be taken to deal with such situations properly.

---

**Sources**:

- [Equality before the law - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equality_before_the_law)
- [Golden Rule - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Rule)
- [Citizen's arrest - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizen%27s_arrest)

Comment: @raham no, you don't, and you shouldn't because it would be against the law.  One lawful course of action would be to call the police and have them handle the matter, as I've said in other comments, as also suggested in this answer.  Another lawful option would be to confront the shoplifter and persuade the shoplifter (without resorting to threats of force) to return the item voluntarily.  This might be quite likely to work with some people and quite unlikely to work with others.

Comment: @raham It's worth noting that some jurisdictions do have the concept of *citizen's arrest,* whereby someone who is not a law enforcement officer may detain someone under certain circumstances until an officer arrives. This is risky and generally not recommended, but it explains how a store's private security guard can detain suspected shoplifters. Someone effecting a citizen's arrest does not have the same powers as an officer, however, so the power to arrest does not imply the power to search the arrested person nor to seize items in the person's possession.

Comment: @raham Just as others don't have the right to violate your property, you don't have the right to violate theirs. [Citizen's arrest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizen%27s_arrest) is a completely different question and should be asked separately.

Comment: Isnt that assault with a different  justification and isnt assault a property violation

Answer (score -3):

I am almost certain the answer is yes because otherwise shoplifting would be extremely  easy. For example if a shoplifter puts an item in their car or bag or something  you would have to assault or burglarize them to get it back. So in the absence of other answers I think you get an easement to retrieve your property.

Comment: Please explain  the downvote

Comment: Yeah, in the absence of permission, you **would** have to assault someone or illegally enter their property. You don't magically get an exception from breaking the law just because someone else broke it first.

Comment: Because an answer should not just be your personal opinion of what make sense. It should ideally contain some research on what the law actually says. References would be nice. In this case I downvoted because what you wrote is simply incorrect. In general you are not allowed to trespass or commit other crimes in the course of reclaiming your property.

Comment: In that case any store grabbing shoplifters is breaking the law. Or searching their bag or anything.

Comment: The correct course of action after a shoplifter has put stolen goods into a bag or a car is to call the police and let the police recover the stolen goods.

Comment: @Nij what doesn't follow?

Comment: raham's previous comment. It wasn't worth explaining further, there are already plenty of questions on what can and can't be done about others breaking the law. @phoog