# Stealing my pet back?

Tags: criminal-law, theft

I was dating this guy for about a month. Within that,He convinced me to let my bird stay with him and he, my dad, and I all agreed that I would get her back if we broke up. Texted him last night and he’s refusing to give her to me and says I can come see her. If I take her without using physical force(unless needed) would I get in any sort of trouble with the law?

Comment: He’s also gas lighting me saying that never happened and he never made an agreement to that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If someone steals something of mine, is it legal to steal it back?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/15869/if-someone-steals-something-of-mine-is-it-legal-to-steal-it-back)

Comment: Do you have proof (texts, etc.) of that agreement?

Comment: Sadly no, I’m doing what I can though with what I have

Answer (score 3):

You don't state a jurisdiction, but the following will apply in most common-law jurisdictions.

If you entered with permission, picked up the bird and walked out with it without any objections then a charge of theft would not stick; you were simply reclaiming your own property with the permission of the householder.

However from your post that doesn't sound likely. If your ex objects to you taking the bird then they can call the police. The police will refuse to get involved in arguments about ownership and will just act to preserve the status quo ante. As long as you haven't broken in or acted deceitfully then you haven't committed a crime, but they are  unlikely to let you take the bird as long as the person with possession claims legal title.

If you try to "steal it back" then you will be guilty of theft, and possibly burglary, criminal damage and maybe other crimes depending on how you did it. Don't go there.

You probably need to file some kind of civil case for the return of your property. Details will depend on the jurisdiction, but if you can get a court order for possession then the police should accept that as evidence that you are acting legally when you turn up to reclaim your property. However (again, depending on jurisdiction) you might need to hire a specialist to do the actual repossession; the laws about gaining entry, searching property etc tend to be complicated and you don't want to get on the wrong side of them.

This is all on the assumption that the value of the bird is lower than the likely cost of hiring a lawyer. If this is an expensive bird then you need legal advice.

Comment: Being an expensive bird is irrelevant. Perhaps it's a way to measure how much you love your animal.

Comment: I’ve had her for two-three years and got her for my birthday from my father when she was 2 months old. She’s attached to me and I’m her “person” so I’m just really upset about this. I’m just doing what I can and I wanted to know what I can do legally and make sure I do everything cleanly without getting into trouble with law on my part

Comment: @KaidenGill If it matters that much, get a lawyer.